# Ruby on Rails screen scrape error - "You must enable javascript in your browser to use this application"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I have a Ruby on Rails web application in which I need to do some screen scrapes.

This is my general call:

curl_results = `#{kinit_command} curl -o curl_results.html -s -L --negotiate -u : \"http://yay.this.site.scrapes.fine\"`

and I get plenty of results in the curl_results.html file.

However, when I try to do certain sites that apparently use javascript - I get the following in the curl_results.html, and nothing much else...

```
<noscript>
<div class="message">You must enable javascript in your browser to use this application.    </div>
</noscript>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

The server is possibly rejecting curl as the user agent. Have you tried changing the user agent (with option -A) to some recent chrome user agent string (e.g. "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36 OPR/18.0.1284.49") ?